# find common data from two rows and data is separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql

I am new learner for php. I am facing problem to solve below query.
I have the following table

```
--------------------------------------
Items        T_id
--------------------------------------
I1--------   T1,T4,T5,T7,T7,T8,T9  
I2--------   T1, T2, T3, T4, T6, T8, T9  
I3--------   T5, T6, T7, T8, T9
```

Now I want to find common items from two rows  and data is separated by comma.

```
--------------------------------------
Items        T_id
--------------------------------------
I1,I2-----   T1,T4,T8,T9  
I2,I3-----   T6,T8,T9
```

also want to find common transactions id for three rows

```
--------------------------------------
Items        T_id
--------------------------------------
I1,I2,I3--   T8,T9
```

anyone have ideas or thoughts on the above?
Pls give answer.

Comment: Yes. Normalize your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample shows a row that, if comming from a database query, it is not normalized. If data is on a database the first step is normaillize it and then you may use inner joins.

Otherwise you may want to check [array_intersect documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and apply it iteratively over your
rows.

- Get first and second rows into an array (you may use explode)
- Calculate its intersection (name it **rowIntersection**)
- Get third row into an array
- Calculate its intersection with **rowIntersection**
- and repeat until you are out of rows

Finally implode the resulting arrays using "," as separator.

Regards

Comment: The sample shows a row that is not normalized. If data is on a database the first step is normaillize it and then you may use joins.

Comment: Added the comment on the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
$sql=select * from table;

$arr=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $arr[]=explode(',',$row['T_id']);
}

$arr_merge=array();
foreach($arr as $value){
    $arr_merge[]=array_merge($arr_merge,$value)
}

$arr_val[]=array_intersect($arr_merge);
```

Comment: changed as per your said